# Dividing a single cell by a column and transposing it horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table: The month column is each month of 2019. Assigned column represents the amount assigned to an account in their respective month. So for 01-2019, the account was assigned 35000.
cumulative_jan column shows how much of the assigned amount is collected in the given month. The 0-->11 columns represent how much time has passed since assignment. I need to check, for each passing month since the month of assignment, how much has been collected. For the 01-2019 values, I need to divide 100 by 35000 and replace the first NULL value under [0]. Next, I need to divide 250 by 35000 and replace the first NULL value under [1] etc. At the end, I have to divide 1500 by 35000 and replace the first NULL under [11].

```
Month    Assigned   cumulative_jan         0     1     2     3  ...   11
01-2019   35000           100             NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL     NULL
02-2019   16500           250             NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL     NULL
.           .              .        
.           .              .
.           .              .
12-2019   87520          1500             NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL     NULL
```

At the end, solely for the January part, I wish to have my table look like this:

```
Month    Assigned   cumulative_jan         0     1     2     3  ...   11
01-2019   35000           100             .003  .007  .01   .015     .04
02-2019   16500           250             NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL     NULL
.           .              .        
.           .              .
.           .              .
12-2019   87520          1500             NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL     NULL
```

I am new to SQL, I am still thinking in Python syntax, so nothing I tried worked. The code that got me here is :

```
select month, assigned, cumulative_jan,[0], [1], [2], [3] , [4] , [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] from baban 
inner join
    (select t1.transdate as date1, sum(t2.col) as cumulative_jan from jan as t1
    inner join jan as t2 on t1.transdate >= t2.transdate group by t1.transdate)
    as col on baban.month= col.date1
    order by month
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results, along with your attempt(s) will help us help you here.

Comment: Your data model looks extremely suspect. I would suggest redoing this question with what problem you are trying to solve and getting input on a proper data model to use.